# wordet synset in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I am using `wordnet.synset()` function in my code

```
>>> cb = wordnet.synset('fever.n.01')
>>> cb
Synset('fever.n.01')

>>> cb = wordnet.synset('disbelieve.n.01')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 3, in <module>
    cb = wordnet.synset('disbelieve.n.01')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1016, in synset
    raise WordNetError(message % (lemma, pos))
WordNetError: no lemma 'disbelieve' with part of speech 'n'

>>> cb = wordnet.synset('disbelieve.v.01')
>>> cb
Synset('disbelieve.v.01')
```

'disbelieve.v.01' exists in wordnet. But the nltk.pos_tag tags it as noun.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag('disbelieve')
>>> tagged
[('disbelieve', 'NN')]
```

Going forward I will be using wordnet's synset similarity function. I do not want to check for pos tags as there is a fair chance of above mentioned error.

So I would want to know if there is any function in nltk that checks if a word beginning with(say, 'disbelieve') exists in wordnet then get the complete wordnet stored form of the word(i.e. 'disbelieve.v.01')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `list` of the synsets for any given word by doing,

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('disbelieve')
[Synset('disbelieve.v.01')]
```

An idea might be to favor those synsets where the POS tag matches that of your tagger, otherwise just pick the first of the list.

Comment: aah Thanks... this solves my problem. but does it throw an exception if the word is not in wordnet dict...

Comment: @user1946217 No, for example `wn.synsets('foobar')` results in an empty list, `[]`